# Give subscribers the option to post anonymously

Tags: comments

I'm looking for a way to allow subscribers to post or comment anonymously. Basically it would be a checkbox at the end of the comment form, exactly like [beyond the shock](http://beyondtheshock.com/questions/361). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can allow anonymous comments in WordPress in `wp-admin/options-discussion.php`:

[image]

Just do not check *Comment author must fill out name and e-mail*.

There is a small usability catch: Sometimes users may just *forget* to fill in their data. I have added a small JavaScript confirm message box asking if they really want to send as anonymous user.